# unable to replace white space in R

Tags: r

I am pasting below output of my head command of a BSE stock data column which I use for R programming practice. I googled and tried almost every trick but I am not able to clear white spaces at the end of these values. It seems that all the strings have fixed width of 12 and after characters I see white space which I am unable to remove.

not sure if this will paste in exact same way(e.g. i see a lot of white space after word HDFC in its double quotes)  but no technique helped me get rid of those trailing whitespaces.

```
head(BSE_stock_data$sc_name)
[1] "ABB LTD.    " "AEGIS LOGIS " "AMAR RAJA BA" "A.SARABHAI  " "HDFC        " "ANDHRA PETRO"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R, without regex:

```
BSE_stock_data$sc_name <- trimws(BSE_stock_data$sc_name)
```

`trimws` stands for *"trim white space"*.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix this with `sub` and a regular expression.

```
BSE_stock_data$sc_name = sub("\\s+$", "", BSE_stock_data$sc_name)

[1] "ABB LTD."     "AEGIS LOGIS"  "AMAR RAJA BA" "A.SARABHAI"   "HDFC"        
[6] "ANDHRA PETRO"
```

Details:

```
\\s    matches any whitespace character
\\s+   matches one or more whitespace characters
$      ties the match to the end of the string
```

So the sub statement will identify any string of whitespace characters at the end of the string and replace it with the empty string.